# Side by side plot display for different traces in plotly

Tags: plotly, plotly-python

This is a snippet of my dataframe:

```
api_group   commit_date type_of_change  count
Other           2015    Non-Breaking    23
Mature          2016    Non-Breaking    96
Developing      2022    Breaking        2
Legacy          2022    Non-Breaking    3
Other           2019    Non-Breaking    148
Legacy          2018    Non-Breaking    5
Early           2019    Breaking        1793
Legacy          2021    Non-Breaking    12
Early           2016    Breaking        711
Mature          2022    Non-Breaking    30
```

I am trying to plot this graph:

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go

new['commit_date'] = pd.to_datetime(new['commit_date'])

df_grouped = new.groupby([new['api_group'], new['commit_date'].dt.year, 'type_of_change'])['type_of_change'].count().reset_index(name='count')

figs = []
for api_group in df_grouped['api_group'].unique():
    breaking_pivot = df_grouped[df_grouped['api_group'] == api_group].pivot_table(index='commit_date', columns='type_of_change', values='count', fill_value=0)

    fig = go.Figure()
    
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=breaking_pivot.index, y=breaking_pivot['Breaking'], name='Breaking', line=dict(dash='solid'), line_width=2.5))
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=breaking_pivot.index, y=breaking_pivot['Non-Breaking'], name='Non-Breaking', line=dict(dash='dot'), line_width=2.5))

    fig.update_layout(title=f'Evolution of Breaking Changes Over Time for {api_group}', width=600, height=500, template='ggplot2', xaxis_title='Year', yaxis_title='Number of Releases')
    
    figs.append(fig)

for fig in figs:
    fig.show()
```

For every `api_group`, it displays the breaking and non breaking changes in it, but the issue is it plots all the graphs for all the 5 groups in a line, but I want them displayed side by side. The graph is this: [image]

Is there a way I could do this, because I am not sure how to plot multiple traces using `subplot` function in plotly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I slightly changed your data to have a better example

## Data

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

data = [['Developing', 2022, 'Breaking', 2],
       ['Early', 2016, 'Breaking', 711],
       ['Early', 2019, 'Breaking', 1793],
       ['Legacy', 2018, 'Non-Breaking', 5],
       ['Legacy', 2021, 'Non-Breaking', 12],
       ['Legacy', 2022, 'Non-Breaking', 3],
       ['Mature', 2016, 'Non-Breaking', 96],
       ['Mature', 2022, 'Non-Breaking', 30],
       ['Other', 2015, 'Non-Breaking', 23],
       ['Other', 2019, 'Non-Breaking', 148],
       ['Other', 2017, 'Breaking', 15],
       ['Other', 2019, 'Breaking', 5]]

df = pd.DataFrame(
        data, 
        columns=[
            'api_group',
            'commit_date',
            'type_of_change',
            'count'])
```

Now ou want to be sure data is correclty ordered

```py
df = df.sort_values(
    ["api_group",
     "type_of_change",
     "commit_date"])\
    .reset_index(drop=True)
```

## Plot

```py
# here we leverage plotly express for
# subplots
fig = px.line(
    df,
    x="commit_date",
    y="count",
    facet_col="api_group",
    color="type_of_change")

# here I change to `dot` in case we are plotting
# 'Non-Breaking'
for d in fig.data:
    if d["legendgroup"] == 'Non-Breaking':
        d["line"]["dash"] = "dot"

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: The facet_col works perfectly for me, although I still cannot plot all my api_groups together, since all of them have very different counts, which leads to the groups with quite less number, essentially coming as a straight line if plotted together. But, I was able to plot three and two together, which was quite beneficial. Thank you so much for taking the time to answer, and explain it in detail!!

Answer (score 0):

When the added sample data is the data after data processing, the subplot for each api_group will draw a line graph with the data extracted in the api_group. A dictionary of line types is prepared beforehand, and line type names are searched in the dictionary from the column values. The subplot specification is added to the graph specification, assuming 5 columns per row; for 5 rows and 1 column, the setting is reversed.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

line_dashs = {'Breaking': 'solid', 'Non-Breaking': 'dot'}
api_groups = new['api_group'].unique()

#fig = go.Figure()
fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=len(api_groups), subplot_titles=api_groups)

for i,api_group in enumerate(new['api_group'].unique()):
    breaking_pivot = new.query('api_group == @api_group')
    #print(breaking_pivot)
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(mode='markers+lines',
                             x=breaking_pivot['commit_date'],
                             y=breaking_pivot['count'],
                             name=api_group,
                             line=dict(dash=line_dashs[breaking_pivot.loc[:,'type_of_change'].unique()[0]]),
                             line_width=2.5,
                            ), row=1, col=i+1)

fig.update_layout(width=1250,
                 height=500,
                 template='ggplot2',
                 xaxis_title='Year',
                 yaxis_title='Number of Releases')
fig.update_xaxes(type='date', tickformat='%Y')

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This approach does not work for my data, since it's huge and everything gets jumbled up when i run it.

Comment: The question doesn't even say that the data is huge, I think you need to clarify what the difference is between an express and a graph object.